# Joomla Search returns invalid weblink URLs (SEO Friendly URL's not working)

Tags: .htaccess, url, seo, joomla2.5, joomla-sef-urls

When the Global_Configuration/Site/SEO_Options are set to:

**Search Engine Friendly URLs:  Yes**

I come across errors with the weblinks...

If you navigate through the menu items to weblink, it will present you with a working URL:

```
www.mywebsite.com/links?task=weblink.go&id=101 = Correct
```

Using the Search utility to find the same weblink will return the following URL:

```
www.mywebsite.com/component/weblinks/2-other-21591/101-flanchford-bridge-scc-news-page?Itemid=180 = Broken, not working.
```

If I set:

**Search Engine Friendly URLs:  No**

Both the Search & Navigation through the menu items will return a working URL:

Through Menu item navigation:

```
www.mywebsite.com/index.php?option=com_weblinks&task=weblink.go&id=101&Itemid=66
```

Through the Search:

```
www.mywebsite.com/index.php?option=com_weblinks&view=weblink&id=101:flanchford-bridge-scc-news-page&catid=2:other-21591&Itemid=180
```

**Request:**

Please can you help me find a solution so that I can keep SEF URL's turned 'ON', and to have the joomla search function return working links. As I currently get 404 pages when clicking a weblink found on a search result...

Please do not advice me to simply 'why not keep it off then?', because I have 1000's of links setup on the site and would like to keep SEF 'ON'

Thank you for reading this.

Any Comments or Contributions are very welcome.

Comment: http://docs.joomla.org/Search_Engine_Friendly_URLs

Comment: http://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component

Comment: 2.4.14 .... migrated from 1.5 though (using JUpgrade PRO)

links and categories have been remade in the 2.5.14 admin interface

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the menu is messed up. (Yes i know you said the menu one works.) Try recreating the menu item.

Otherwise

Maybe you modified/overrided a file in components\com_weblinks\?
Look at last mod date. Maybe have a look at components\com_weblinks\router.php

```
function ContentParseRoute()
```